What experiments have been done which demonstrate that immediately after measurement, the collapsed state evolves unitarily again?
I am a high school teacher and in the coming year, I will introduce quantum mechanics to my AP physics course (I'm not actually in the US school system, but high school and AP physics are the closest analogies). A quantum mechanics unit starts with unconfined systems (mainly the photoelectric effect and interference patterns of electrons) and ends with confined systems (the hydrogen atom in a very simplified manner). I fear that due to the experiments involved in the beginning of the unit, the following misconception might come up:

After measurement, the system is either destroyed or becomes classical.

For instance, in the photoelectric effect, photons are absorbed, and the movement of the absorbing electron, often in an electric field, is treated classically. Or after an electron hits the detection screen, it presumably remains there in some capacity and students might assume that the spot on the screen is where the electron now sits like a classical particle at rest.
What I need:
I need an actual experimental result demonstrating that after measurement, the collapsed state will evolve according to the rules of quantum mechanics again. And ideally this experiment should be understandable by advanced high school students after suitable simplifications.

A simple slit-diffraction experiment shows this. Whenever a particle successfully passes through the slit, its position is projected onto the region of the slit, after which it evolves freely again.

A measurement is simply an irreversible energy transfer between the quantum system and the measurement system. The state of the quantum system after the measurement has the measured quantum of energy less than before. When we consider the measurement finished is up to us, of course. If we want perfect energy resolution, then the experiment is never finished. Because of time-energy uncertainty the measurement has to take an infinite amount of time.

@FlatterMann In a dual slit experiment or a Mach-Zehnder interferometer any measurement of which way information breaks down the interference pattern. Placing a polarizing filter  in either path counts as a measurement and the interference breaks down. Does the polarising filter cause an irreversible energy transfer between the quantum system and the measurement system?

@KDP A polarization filter removes half the energy from the system if the initial light was randomly polarized. It doesn't change anything about what I said.

The entire premise of this experiment is ill-guided. You're implying that something non-unitary happens during a measurement, which is false.

The sequential Stern Gerlach might work, though it typically involves filtering rather than explicit observation before the end. You can reformulate any filtering as a measurement.
Otherwise, a good choice is any realization of the quantum Zeno effect, which explicitly shows that you need to keep observing a system to keep from evolving unitarily, while it goes back to unitary evolution when you stop observing.

A Stern-Gerlach is a proper measurement because at some point we do measure the energy of the silver atoms. The important thing to realize is that we are measuring the energy of the atoms and not the atoms themselves. That's why it doesn't matter what we use in such a measurement. It can be silver atoms or neutrons. (Electrons are not a good idea because of their charge, which messes up the experiment, but that has nothing to do with the quantization of angular momentum.).

Collapse is incompatible with the quantum zeno effect or any other kind of continuous measurement https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973

@FlatterMann The Stern-Gerlach experiment measures position of atoms after they pass through the magnet. There is no measurement of energy of atoms. We can calculate what potential energy in the magnetic field they had just before they got captured by a screen, from the position of the mark the atom made, and magnetic field there.

Repeated measurement does not keep the system "classical", the system just remains close to the initial state. This state is still quantum, e.g. spin state $|z+\rangle$ does not imply any definite value of spin projection on axis $x$.

Good point @JánLalinský, I've reworded the answer to clarify that observation interrupts unitary evolution, not making anything classical.

@JánLalinský I have yet to see a detector that doesn't remove energy from the system. This can't be any other way because of the third law of thermodynamics. The energy removed has to be above kT of the detector to be distinguishable from noise. I know that this isn't discussed in the theory and it doesn't matter for most of what the theory does, but it is of vital importance to ontological questions about the nature of quantum mechanics which touch upon the question of what physical reality is. Reality is everything that leaves a memory. That requires energy.

@FlatterMann you wrote "we measure the energy of the atoms". Do you take that back and now claim that e.g. particle position detector removes energy from the particle? How do you know that, if we do not measure energy of the particle?

@JánLalinský We are always measuring energy (momentum, angular momentum and charge). That there has to be a net energy transfer follows directly from the third law of thermodynamics. The measurement system has an effective temperature T. Only measurement outcomes that are above kT can be separated from thermal noise. Yes, even a position detector measures energy, we just don't care about the amount of energy. I don't believe I said otherwise. At least I didn't try to claim otherwise. Was my language muddled on that point?

@FlatterMann How is photographic screen showing a dot due to interaction with particle measuring energy? The particle leaves a mark, that's it. No idea about its energy is obtained.Yes, exchange of energy may have taken place, but this does not mean we "measured energy".

@Codename47 is right, I think the best experiment to explain how orthodox quantum theory thinks about experiments on quantum systems (including collapse of quantum state on measurement and validity of the Schroedinger equation after it) is the Stern-Gerlach experiment and its variants with several chained magnets and filtering. So I recommend to search for actual experiments with chained SG magnets. I don't know if these (chained magnets and filtering) were actually done, but Feynman discusses them in detail in his lectures. It is also possible these were never done, so they are really a thought experiment; but even then, they are still useful, to explain how quantum theory works.
Also useful, but I think more prone to introduce misconceptions, is the double slit experiment on atoms or electrons with detection of which hole the particle went. Again, I am not sure if they were actually done. All these experiments seem to have been made up to demonstrate how to think in quantum theory, and only later maybe they were done in some form by somebody, and almost no one has read that experimental paper.
Perhaps it is good to explain both experiments. They have something in common, such as unitary evolution before detection, detection resulting in discrete like result of measurement (which spin projection, which hole), and unitary evolution after that. They have also important differences, such as spin description is always discrete, while position is traditionally continuous, and only sometimes (two holes, particle passes through without being lost) we can get discrete results of measurement, but in other cases (screen the particle gets captured in), the measurement result is treated mathematically as continuous and the system gets lost.
I think SG experiments are best to start with because the spin part of quantum state of silver atom, as compared to a position part of quantum state of electron or atom, is a finite-dimensional thing, so the mathematics is simpler and easily explicitly tractable. And experimentally, beams with known spin state can be prepared and manipulated by sequential application of SG magnet + path filtering, without the system of interest (flying atom with a spin) getting lost in a screen or detector after the first measurement. However, this can get quite technical and boring, so to keep students interested, I recommend talking about expectations and surprising results a lot, and repeatedly mentioning them and comparing them, and promising the theory they are about to learn can explain much of it.
Applying the usual simple postulates to continuous quantities (position, momentum) results in mathematical and conceptual difficulties and a need for reformulating the postulates, so they are consistent with the actual practice of using quantum theory for them (Born rule for position or angles in scattering, there are no eigenstates for position or momentum, non-normalizable states, alternative normalizations, etc.) This is not easy. Also, an experiment with repeated measurement of continuous quantities is not easy to find - as you mention, usually the system is lost, either in a detector, or flies away.
So I think in introductory course aiming to teach ideas of quantum theory, while it is probably good to talk about or even start with experiments with photoeffect, electron diffraction/interference patterns, hydrogen gas spectra or blackbody radiation (so that students  have some good motivation and reliable facts for studying and accepting quantum theory), it is not very good to jump right then into fully explaining the mathematical details of quantum theory of those experiments, even if they are pretty early in the historical progression. Full theoretical view of these are really topics for advanced courses on quantum theory.
The simplified postulates work well for discrete quantities such as spin, so the course should start with actual experiments on those, and use those examples with their easy mathematics to explain the basic ideas of quantum theory.
With those basic ideas understood, it is easier to study the harder parts of the theory about continuous quantities.

Several people here suggest using the Stern-Gerlach experiment for your experiment, but this is not a practical experiment to carry out in a classroom. If you want to actually do a real experiment for your students in a classroom environment, you can do a very similar demonstration just using polarised photons, which is much simpler. Get a light source and pass it through a polarising beam splitter crystal. These crystals split the beam and send photons with vertical polarisation one way and photons with horizontal polarisation the other way. You can place normal polarising filters in the two paths and rotate them until you get maximum transmission of light intensity on each beam and then decide which beam you want to call the vertical orientation (let's say it is the left side) and the other filter should be at $90^\circ$ to the vertical filter. These secondary filters effectively act as measurement devices. All the photons that went left have vertical polarisation and have no horizontal component. We can confirm this by placing yet another vertical polariser on the left path with little or no diminution of brightness. Now, place a second polarising beam splitter on the left path. If all the photons on the left path have vertical polarisation, they should go one way at the second beam splitter, but that is not what happens. The left beam will split again, demonstrating that when we thought we had measured the photons to have vertical polarisation, they were still in a superposition of vertical and horizontal polarisations.
If your budget does not run to polarising beam splitter crystals, you can do a similar demonstration using basic polarising filters. Pass a light source through a vertical polarising filter. A second filter at right angles to the first will block all the light, demonstrating that the photons that pass through the first vertical filter have no horizontal component. Now, place a third filter between the first two at $45^\circ$. Some of the light now passes through the horizontal filter. This is because the photons coming out of the first polariser that we assumed we had measured to have a purely vertical polarisation are actually still in a superposition of vertical and horizontal polarisation components. The third filter in the middle at $45^\circ$ makes a measurement. This experiment tells us that making a measurement changes what we are measuring (The photons can now pass through the final filter after making this middle measurement.) It also tells us that when we make a measurement, we never get complete information about the original state and that even after making a measurement, the particle can still be in a superposition of states.

Nice answer (+1) I am fascinated by the Stern Gerlach experiment. In the polarizer version you mentioned, the middle polarizer itself is a crystal, right? There are known crystals (eg. LCD) that can flip the polarization of light passing through... so is there a watertight argument that the polarization of the light after passing through the 45 degree polarizer crystal has not become random again because of its non-linear interaction with the crystal itself?

@james The middle polariser is just a regular polarising filter like a lens from polarising sunglasses or just one of those cheap polarising filter sheets you can buy. I am only assuming Malus Law.

I am mainly suspicious about the 45 degree angle. Suppose the polarizer is a horizontal fence. Then it allows the horizontal wave to pass, but blocks the vertical wave. At 45 degree angle though, this fence might actually behave non-linearly, for e.g. could you predict exactly what waves will form / will not form if one of the fence is tilted at 45 degree in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyxBybgfKP8 ?

If you rotate your screen 45 degrees that is what the 45 degree angle polariser would look like. Polarisation doesn't really care about gravity. Actually, the video is poor representation of how polarisation works. If a photon is polarised anywhere between $+ 45^{\circ}$ and $- 45^{\circ}$ from the vertical when it enters the vertical polariser, it will come out with a polarisation of anywhere between $+ 45^{\circ}$ and $- 45^{\circ}$ , with a higher probability of being near vertical. The angle it comes out with, is unrelated to the angle it came in.

In the Stern-Gerlach experiment, you start with particles of random spin. The beam is sent through a magnet that can be orientated to send particle with up spin one way and down spin the other way. This is the first bit of quantum weirdness. There is no spread of the spin orientations. Instead we get a binary result, up or down. If we send the beam where we measured the particles to have up spin through a second magnet, the beam is split again into up and down spin particles. The weird thing is we thought that beam only contained up spin particles. The measurement scrambles orientation.

In the original Stern Gerlach experiment, might the presence of the strong magnetic field of the detector itself flip the spin of the electron https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article-abstract/100/12/121112/23876/Spin-flip-probability-of-electron-in-a-uniform?redirectedFrom=fulltext ?

@James I guess that is possible, but the ordinary polariser experiment exhibits the same sort of behavior and there are no strong magnetic fields involved there. The fact that measuring the state of a particle alters the state of the particle appears to be an inherent part of quantum mechanics.

Here may be an argument for the polarizer setup: just replace the middle polarizer with an actual liquid crystal. Now switching the voltage on/off (i.e. rotating the molecules of the liquid crystal) is exactly like our manual turning of the polarizer, right? So the light polarization is definitely getting messed up due to the polarizer/liquid crystal being rotated & doing something to the polarization of the light passing through...

@James As I understand it a LCD device is actually 3 polarisers sandwiched together. The two outer layers are regular polarising filters that are perpendicular to each other. The middle layer is effectively a third polariser whose orientation changes when the voltage is altered. It is effectively the 3 polariser experimental set up I described in miniature.

Yeah. I am a little confused too now as to what we agree and what we disagree :)

@James Hopefully we agree that when a particle passes through a measurement device its state is randomised by the measurement and uncertain within certain constraints. For example, if the photons entering a vertical polarising filter have the full 360 degree spectrum of possible orientations, but when the 50% that pass through exit, their orientations are randomised but constrained to + or -45 degrees from vertical. Malus law gives the probability that they will have a given orientation.

Yes, I believe we do agree that the process of measurement changes/randomizes the state to some extent. I believe quantum theory states that this randomization is fundamental (without mechanism), while I was just arguing that a non-linear mechanism might be causing this randomization, that seems to be the issue?

This is a nice experiment because it shows how properties of quantum measurement (state preparation), which quantum theory has for spin, arise already in classical physics with EM radiation polarization. However, it would be very hard to demonstrate in a class experiment where and why quantum theory is necessary here, so both SG and polarization experiment showing non-classical quantum behaviour are hard to do.

@JánLalinský Can the experiment with polarising beam splitters ,where the beam is split, then passed through a vertical polariser and then the beam is split again (with photons being detected going both ways after the second polarising beam splitter) be explained in purely classical terms?

@KDP depends on what you mean by "photons being detected". If you mean just detecting light intensity of usual (strong) laser light, then classical wave optics should explain all observations, the light is close to coherent states and not photon states. If instead very sensitive detectors are used with weak light and noise is suppressed enough, then observed statistics of detections  (e.g. anti-bunching) is generally considered evidence for photons, and thus for a need of quantum description. However, this has also been contested by some mathematicians (Santos, Marshall).

@KDP They have papers making arguments to the effect that all known "photon statistics experiments" can be explained using classical theory of EM radiation. I too have some doubts about interpretation of the first antibunching experiments (Clauser). But I don't know enough about these experiments and the theory to say whether they are right or not.

Nothing non-unitary happens during a measurement, in fact a measurement is just an interaction described by a Hamiltonian. Instead of teaching outdated concepts like collapse you should look into decoherence.

Collapse is perfectly consistent with experiments, and it is the standard way QM is taught here both in school and university. I'm not going to go against the grain here. Even though I personally like collapse free interpretations.

Really QM for high school?  You should start by saying QM was invented in the 1930s/1940s and that WWII took all the best scientists into the nuclear age ... leaving QM at kind of a dead end and subject to a lot of interpretation by academics.
The Schrodinger equation just says if we use Maxwell like properties/equations for EM waves we can describe the electron in orbit as a probability function.  Be careful of superposition it's a mathematical convenience and not a version of reality.
Experiments with polarizers are great .... they just accept light of all angles and emit at only one angle .... when we put another polarizer in the path say at 45 we just accept 50% of incoming polarized light and spit it out at another angle .... thereby making acceptable to a third polarizer.   The DSE is no mystery ... the excited electron on the atom works with the EM field long before emission.

Quantum theory states that you can prepare a system in a superposition state and that the different possible states in the superposition can interfere with one another and this has been experimentally tested see:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
and "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch chapter 2.
It is common for people to say that measurement of a system in a superposition results in a process called collapse that selects one element out of the superposition. This idea of collapse is inconsistent with the equations of motion of quantum theory and there is no variant of quantum theory that includes collapse that explains results of quantum experiments:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
The reason you only see one version of a system in unmodified quantum theory is very different. When a quantum system interacts with other systems that copy information out of it quantum interference is suppressed:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
For the objects you see in everyday life, information is copied out of them a lot faster than they evolve, e.g. - by air molecules, light, the chair you're sitting on and that sort of thing. As a result interference is heavily suppressed and you don't diffract when you walk through a door.
For systems under carefully controlled conditions, the extent of decoherence can be tuned and tested, see the experiments described in Section 6 of the review linked above. I would guess Sections 6.1 or 6.2 might be explainable to students.

I feel like this is at most tangentially related to my question. I am working in the framework of the Copenhagen interpretation and while other mechanisms to explain what the Copenhagen interpretation sees as a collapse, my question is about experiments demonstrating unitary evolution after measurement. Nothing more, nothing less.

@Vercassivelaunos Decoherence doesn't explain what the Copenhagen interpretation sees as collapse. One reason for this is that the CI doesn't explain how collapse takes place and it is impossible for any theory to reproduce results that don't exist. How can one reproduce this? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Cartoon-then-a-miracle-occurs_fig1_370467655 Decoherence explains the implications of quantum theory and can be applied in a very wide range of circumstances where collapse is inapplicable https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
